# Can you combine (append) Paths onto each other?

Tags: swift, path, append, google-maps-sdk-ios, coordinate

So if I have firstPath, secondPath, and thirdPath, could I make a new path like this:

```
finalPath = firstPath
finalPath.append(secondPath)
finalPath.append(thirdPath)
```

Thanks!

The only other way I could think to do this would be to just go with:

```
for coord in firstPath
{
finalPath.add(coord)
}

for coord in secondPath
{
finalPath.add(coord)
}

for coord in thirdPath
{
finalPath.add(coord)
}
```

and that just seems tedious

Comment: What type is `firstPath`? Most people who would otherwise be able to answer your question won't be able to due to the lack of background. Most of us aren't familiar with the google maps sdk.

Comment: all the "paths" are of type GMSMutablePath

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your loops:

```
for path in [firstPath, secondPath, thirdPath] {
    for coord in path {
        finalPath.add(coord)
    }
}
```